# sudo host field: what is it used for?

Tags: sudo

syntax for `sudo` is

`user ALL=(ALL) ALL` whereby:

> 1st field is the user that can execute `sudo`
>
> 3rd field is the users that can be `sudo` into
>
> 4th field is the commands that can be executed as `sudo`

**2nd** field is to put the host(s) in which the `sudo` can be run on.

=================================

I do not understand the use of **2nd** field. How do we enable `sudo` on host A for the use on another host B ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2nd **ALL**= on all hosts (if you distribute the same `sudoers` file to many computers)

Comment: so the 2nd field is still actually applicable to the local system only right ? it does not enable a user on host A to execute sudo on another right ?

Comment: Not unless you copy that exact same `sudoers` file to the other host.

Answer (score 2):

The [full specification of the sudoers syntax](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.14/sudoers.man.html) is more complex than you've listed. The host specification just tells sudo on which hosts that user is allowed to run those commands. If the host specification is "ALL", which the man page says:

> The reserved word ALL is a built-in alias that always causes a match
>   to succeed. It can be used wherever one might otherwise use a
>   Cmnd_Alias, User_Alias, Runas_Alias, or Host_Alias.

sudo only cares about the sudo rules on the local host; if you run a command that connects to another host, the processing starts over again there.

What may be confusing to you is seeing sudoers configuration for multiple hosts; the only set of rules that apply to a particular host are those with that hostname and "ALL".

Comment: thanks for the explanation but what good does it do to have the host field then ? since all the sudo commands will naturally be issue on that host itself

Comment: As @neuron said, so that a common sudoers file can be distributed across many hosts.

Answer (score 1):

> so the 2nd field is still actually applicable to the local system only right ? it does not enable a user on host A to execute sudo on another right ? –
> Noob

Yes. That file is not a single copy used by all hosts, it's copied as many times as the number of hosts. It's just easier to make a single sudoers file and then give copies of it to multiple hosts.

For a practical example, imagine that you had a few dozen servers that shared like 80% of their sudoers configuration but each of them then had some special configuration on top of that. By using the hosts list, you can give each host the same sudoers file (e.g. giving all those hosts a copy of this file using Ansible) while still having the appropriate per-host configuration.

You should search for the word `host_list` in `man sudoers` and you'll see the EBNF there. As per the sudoers man page, they're "comma-delimited" and can use either a host name, an IP address, a network with optional netmask, a netgroup, or a host alias.

```
Host_List ::= Host |
        Host ',' Host_List

Host ::= '!'* host name |
   '!'* ip_addr |
   '!'* network(/netmask)? |
   '!'* +netgroup |
   '!'* Host_Alias
```